# Understanding the concept of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, dictionary

So this may be a very simple thing for most of you but I'm just starting out.

Below is my first ever class:

```
class WeatherYear:

    DEFAULT_MAX = -99
    DEFAULT_MIN = 999
    DEFAULT_STR = 'DATE'

    def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year
        self.max_temp = WeatherYear.DEFAULT_MAX
        self.min_temp = WeatherYear.DEFAULT_MIN
        self.max_temp_date = WeatherYear.DEFAULT_STR
        self.max_humid = WeatherYear.DEFAULT_MAX
        self.min_humid = WeatherYear.DEFAULT_MIN

    def add_day(self, date, max_temp, min_temp, max_humid, min_humid):
        if max_temp and max_temp > self.max_temp:
            self.max_temp = max_temp
            self.max_temp_date = date
        if min_temp and min_temp < self.min_temp:
            self.min_temp = min_temp
        if max_humid and max_humid > self.max_humid:
            self.max_humid = max_humid
        if min_humid and min_humid < self.min_humid:
            self.min_humid = min_humid
```

And here is some stuff that I used it for:

```
years_dict = {}
wy_obj = years_dict.get(year)

if not wy_obj:
    years_dict[year] = WeatherYear(year)
    wy_obj = years_dict[year]

    wy_obj.add_day(date, max_temp, min_temp, max_humid, min_humid)
```

This is part of my code, could someone please explain to me what is happening exactly, also the major part, **Do i need to keep year in my `__init__` function? What if I remove it? Would it still work the same way?**

Comment: Did you try it out to see?

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah, I did, but I thought if someone explained it a little bit, it might help clear my concepts.
Also I'm unsure if taking out the "year" would mess it up. Took me a long time creating this.

Comment: Well, if you will need that `year` then you have to keep it. Currently, it's not being used anywhere so it's safe to remove it.

Comment: Tried it out multiple times, plus got the concept. The {year} isn't required, my {dict) is doing its part there. Sorry for my beginner level skills, but you guys still helped. Thank you :)

Comment: The problem with removing it is that once a WeatherYear instance is out of the `years_dict` you don't know which year it's related to anymore. So while you technically don't need it for the above use case, it might be worth keeping it nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out the code, that's the best way to understand OOP's concepts in Python.
Coming back to your question, according to your code, you need to have **year** in your **init** function else `self.year = year` would give an *year not defined error*

Comment: Well, it wouldn't if they simply removed it as an attribute altogether

Comment: Yes, removing `self.year = year` altogether wouldn't pose any problem. However if the OP needs to use year compulsorily, then it needs to be declared in the __init__ method.

Comment: It wasn't a requirement in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question>**: Do i need to keep year in my **init** function?

**No**, as you store a date in `self.max_temp_date`, thats doubled as you can get the `year` from date using `self.max_temp_date.year`.

---

Change your `class WetherYear().__init__(...` to the following:

```
def __init__(self, measure):
    self.max_temp_date, self.max_temp, self.min_temp, self.max_humid, self.min_humid = measure
```

Thereby you don't have to initalize the class attributes with dummy values. Set the attributes at once with the first `measure` values.

About your naming of `class methodes`, name it to **what** this function are doing. In this case, you don't **add** anything you **update** the `class attributs` by condition.

> ```
> def add_day(self, date, max_temp, min_temp, max_humid, min_humid):
>     if max_temp and max_temp > self.max_temp:
>        ...
> ```

You don't have to `get(...` the `WeatherYear` object, to test if this `year` exists. use the key `year` only. Also you don't have to get it again `wy_obj = years_dict[year]`, you can use it from the `dict` e.g. `years_dict[year].add_day(...`

> ```
> wy_obj = years_dict.get(year)
>
> if not wy_obj:
>     years_dict[year] = WeatherYear(year)
>     wy_obj = years_dict[year]
>     wy_obj.add_day(...
> ```

---

Consider this example:

```
from datetime import date

class WeatherYear:
    def __init__(self, measure):
        self.max_temp_date, self.max_temp, self.min_temp, self.max_humid, self.min_humid = measure

    def update(self, measure):            
        if measure[1] > self.max_temp:
            self.max_temp_date = measure[0]
            self.max_temp = measure[1]

        if measure[2] > self.min_temp:
            self.min_temp = measure[2]

        if measure[3] > self.max_humid:
            self.max_humid = measure[3]

        if measure[4] > self.min_humid:
            self.min_humid = measure[4]

    def __str__(self):
       return "WeatherYear:In {year} at {self.max_temp_date}, measured a max temperature of {self.max_temp}°C and max humid of {self.max_humid} %".format(self=self, year=self.max_temp_date.year)


def main():
    #          date, max_temp, min_temp, max_humid, min_humid
    measurements = [(date(2018, 9, 10), 20, 8, 40, 30),
                    (date(2018, 9, 12), 25, 12, 50, 35),
                    (date(2018, 9, 13), 19, 10, 30, 25)]

    max_years = {}
    for measure in measurements:
        if not measure[0].year in max_years:
            max_years[measure[0].year] = WeatherYear(measure)
        else:
            max_years[measure[0].year].update(measure)

    for year in max_years:
        print("{}: {}".format(year, max_years[year]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> 2018: WeatherYear:In 2018 at 2018-09-12, measured a max temperature of 25°C, max humid of 50 %
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***